# RDLC export to pdf with high resolution background image

Tags: c#, background-image, rdlc, export-to-pdf, high-resolution

Recently, for one of my current clients, I had to create a RDLC Report. More specifically an invoice on a digital stationary paper. (see “stationary_paper_example.png” [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPQ2v.png)).

### Problems

When a high-resolution image is set as report background the scaling of the image is completely off. See “stationary_paper_falsely_scaled.png” [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OAEn.png)

### Previous workaround

As the reports with digital stationary paper were introduced just a project before, we got it working by setting an image-element in the background (z-index) and set a high-resolution image. But this time we got some new implicit restrictions.

### Implicit restrictions

1. Current page number

The client wanted to show the current page number above the invoice articles table (see "stationary_paper_page_number.png" [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPPdD.png)). You can get this information only in the header or footer section of the report

2. Image-Element

The image element I set as “report background” can’t be placed inside header, body and footer of the report (see "stationary_paper_image_as_background.png" [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbkQc.png))

So either the client would change their report layout or I get this thing going.

### New problems

1. Setting high-resolution image as background

As already mentioned, when you simply set a high-resolution image as background you will (probably) experience a “scaling” bug as seen in “stationary_paper_falsely_scaled.png” [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OAEn.png). The image is rendered almost completely out of scope.

2. Setting low-resolution image as background

If you set a low-res image as background you will (probably) see a kind of fuzzy background as seen in “stationary_paper_low_res.png” [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh5tw.png). This will also happen when you export this solution with a “pdf printer” such as “Microsoft print to pdf”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and testing I finally got it working (at least imo)

### Solution

1. Setting the background of the report

I set the background of the report as following:

```
Source:   External
Value:    ="file:" + Parameters!PathToStationeryPaper.Value
MIMEType: image/jpeg
```

2. Check usage of stationary paper
   As not all reports of the whole software solution use stationary paper, I just check the reports parameter.

```
private bool reportUsesStationaryPaper()
{
   var result = false;
   foreach (var param in reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters())
   {
      if (param.Name.Equals("UsesStationeryPaper"))
      {
         result = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

3. Show low-res image on preview
   In the event “reportviewer_RenderingBegin” I set a low-resolution image to improve performance. You can also set a version of the stationary paper with a watermark here

```
private void reportViewer1_RenderingBegin(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (reportUsesStationaryPaper())
   {
      //Reset report to low-resolution mode for screen rendering
      var pathToStationaryPaper = "[…]/stationary_lowres.png";
      reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("PathToStationeryPaper", pathToStationaryPaper));
   }
}
```

4. Add device info
   In the event “reportviewer_ReportExport” I set the path to a high-resolution image and additionally add device infos (“ReportExportEventArgs.DeviceInfo”) to increase the resolution as the export functionality seems to be able to work with higher quality.

```
private void reportViewer1_ReportExport(object sender, ReportExportEventArgs e)
{
   if (reportUsesStationaryPaper())
   {
      //Reset report to high-resolution mode for printing
      string deviceInfo =
               @"<DeviceInfo>         
                  <DpiX>300</DpiX>
                  <DpiY>300</DpiY>
                 </DeviceInfo>";
      e.DeviceInfo = deviceInfo; 
      var pathToStationaryPaper = "[…]/stationary_highres.png";
      reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("PathToStationeryPaper", pathToStationaryPaper));
   }
}
```

5. [OPT] Show export button
   If you don’t need a separate button to call the export method of the reportviewer element you can just enable it via UI Designer or code

### Result

1. Preview

Higher performance as a lower resolution can be set and, if you want, a “preview” watermark [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVIxb.png)

2. Print on a „pdf printer“ (here „Microsoft print to pdf”)

Still fuzzy as we can’t set the resolution in “reportviewer_PrintingBegin” or “reportviewer_Print”

3. Export with Reportviewer

When exported via export of the reportviewer control you will now get a beautiful high-resolution image as background of the report

### Further consequences

As the users of my client were used to “print to pdf” the client now either needs to train the users to use the reportviewer export button or a separate button “Export to PDF” will be introduced in the view.